# Rails Heroku Sendgrid send to one address in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

We are using Heroku (Staging and Production) with Sendgrid for a Rails 3 app.

Is there a way to have all the emails generated in Staging re-directed to one address.  When testing, we don't want to actually do things like email invoices to our customers.

If not, would we need to program the logic into the mailer?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, this is a common setup. Most of the time you'll use an environment variable to hardcode an "override" email address. You also might want to checkout a service called sendwithus, that uses your SendGrid account and provides configurable API Keys to do this sort of thing, without changing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode the 'to' address in the mailer file.

```
mail(to: "youremail@domain.com", subject: "A new comment has been added to #{list}", from: "some@thing.com")
```

Comment: The app runs in Test, Staging and Production.  It's only in Staging that I want it to be re-directed.

Comment: You could make this line subject to an environment variable i.e. if ENV['ON_STAGING]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [recipient_interceptor](https://github.com/croaky/recipient_interceptor) gem.